# How to show ampersand in facebook ads title

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook ads api. I want to show AT&T in facebook title. When i do not encode & it cut off the parameter and only show AT but when i encode AT&T with AT%26T, it shows AT%26T. How can i show AT&T in facebook ad. 
I call facebook services like https://graph.facebook.com/act_111111/adcreatives?type=1&title=...

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding it twice, once for URL and once for HTML.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/act_111111/adcreatives?type=1&title=AT%26amp%3BT
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to encode AT&T as AT&amp;T in HTML? Note the added ';'

Comment: Now i am sending all parameters as post instead of passing it in querystring and it is working fine. I didn't try your solution but it might work.